# Convertir un Long a TimeStamp en Angular 8

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo esta clase User en Angular 8.2.14:

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public userId: string,
    public account: Account,
    public userName: string,
    public emailAddress: string,
    public password: string,
    public enabled: number,
    public lastLogin: number
  ) {}
}
```

Y en la clase Java de esta entidad está de esta otra forma:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private String userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", referencedColumnName = "accountId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Account account;

    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    @ColumnDefault(value = "1")
    private Integer enabled;

    @Column(name = "lastLogin")
    private Long lastLogin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @Transient
    private Set<UserGroupUser> userGroups = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }
...
}
```

Lo que necesito es mostrar el dato Long a un TimeStamp, estilo "1997-01-11 23:30:00", pero en las pruebas solo me visualiza el año:

[image: Solo muestra año en AngularJS 8.2.14]

**user.component.html** (En esta plantilla HTML brevemente se muestra la generación de la lista de usuarios y el campo lastLogin)

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="users" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="userId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> userId </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.userId}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

...

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="lastLogin">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> lastLogin </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.lastLogin}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"><button ng-hide="user.userName==this.getUser()" class="btn btn-danger"  (click)="deleteUser(user)"> Delete user</button> </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Algún tipo de dato en particular para este escenario, por favor? Solamente se basa en number para grandes cantidades o detalles largos de fecha/hora? Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Por favor, dale a [edit] y añade más información a tu pregunta: ¿El campo lastLogin es un *Unix time? Si es así, ¿Cómo estás obteniendo el año?. ¿Puedes mostrar el código de tu plantilla (template)?

Comment: No es el año lo que quiero obtener en el listado @PabloLozano, sino YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss. Qué puedo indicar en el constructor de AngularJS ese campo para que se visualice, por favor? La BD es MySQL.

Comment: Parece que no me explico bien: ¿Qué te llega de backend? Si sólo te llega un número con el año, no podemos obtener más. Si es un *Unix Time*, se puede transformar.

Comment: A lo mejor es más probable emplear Unix Time @PabloLozano. Cómo se haría, por favor?

Comment: Por lo que veo, el campo lastLogin simplemente guarda el año. El problema está en el lado de Java/ base datos. ¿De qué tipo es la columna lastLogin en la tabla `User`?

Comment: De tipo datetime

Comment: Entonces yo podría el mismo tipo (es decir la clase [java.time.DateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)) para tener los datos, porque parece que ahora mismo tienes sólo el año al transformarlo a un Long

Comment: De acuerdo, @PabloLozano, eso para caso Java, pero en AngularJS qué le indicas al constructor ese campo?

Comment: dependerá de cómo te llegue la información, no sé cómo estás transformando el objeto Java a JSON

Comment: Entiendo, @PabloLozano. Encontré la respuesta. Gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el manejo de las fechas es recomendable transformarlas a clase Date o usar una libreria como [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/).
Para el primer caso, [Date masks](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) pordian ser utiles.
Para el segundo, la documentacion de moment es extensa y tiene muchos ejemplos.

Comment: Otra alternativa interesante. Lo tendré en cuenta también. Muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 1):

He cambiado a String en la entidad User, y de esta forma visualizar mejor los detalles de lastLogin

**User.class**

```
 @Column(name = "lastLogin")
    private String lastLogin;
```

**User constructor AngularJS**

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public userId: string,
    public account: Account,
    public userName: string,
    public emailAddress: string,
    public password: string,
    public enabled: number,
    public lastLogin: string
  ) {}
}
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado visualización después de los cambios]